# Launch bash shell using systemd and have it attach to the current terminal

Tags: bash, systemd, environment-variables, init

What I'm wanting to do is have systemd launch the bash shell and connect it to my current terminal.  The goal is be examine how systemd controls the environment that is created for the processes it launches and what type of environment is created.  I figured having it start a bash shell would show me this information however I'm just not sure how to do that and get the shell connected to the terminal i'm currently using.  All this testing is going in in a VM so there are not any security concerns with the environment at this point.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible at all to connect a bash to your current terminal with systemd. Actially I am not really sure, if I understood the question in detail.

But to get the information on the environment is quiet easy in several ways.

One is the general way to view the environment variables for a process which is already running. Use `/proc` with the process id of the process (exchange `self` with the processid):

```
cat /proc/self/environ | sort -z | xargs -n 1 -0
```

Another way is to write a small bash script writing the environment on execution to a file. Add this to systemd and start it.

```
#!/bin/bash
env > /tmp/testenvironment
```

After starting the systemd you find the environment in `/tmp/testenvironment`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yea I did think about just writing the environment out to a temp file but I really wanted to have the bash shell started by systemd in an environment where I could interact with it.  Back in the day I would created a chrooted environment and put "program A" into it, bash and strace and then I would try to get "program A" to start by adding dependent files and device notes into the jail and then using strace to see where and what it failed to access.  I wanted to be able to do the same thing with systemd.